# Windows Service started and then stopped while I did not found any error in the codes

Tags: vb.net

I have created a service named "IranStockCodal" and Built and installed it "Sucessfully" on windows services, but when I start It a warning comes on windows services window:
"The "IranStockCodal" service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other service or programs". The task "Call vbIranStock.VBNetLib.vbScript4.VbsRun4(False)" which is called works truly in console application, but when I import and call it from service it does not.
please help me what should be done to solve this.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Configuration
Imports vbIranStock.VBNetLib.vbScript4
Imports vbIranStock

Public Class Service1

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
        Me.WriteToFile("Iran Stock Codal started at " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"))
        Call vbIranStock.VBNetLib.vbScript4.VbsRun4(False)
        Me.WriteToFile("Iran Stock Codal Task Called at " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"))
        Me.ScheduleService()

    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
            Me.WriteToFile("Iran Stock Codal Service stopped at " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"))
            Me.Schedular.Dispose()
        End Sub

        Private Schedular As Timer

        Public Sub ScheduleService()
            Try
                Schedular = New Timer(New TimerCallback(AddressOf SchedularCallback))
                Dim mode As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Mode").ToUpper()
                Me.WriteToFile((Convert.ToString("Iran Stock Codal Service Mode: ") & mode) + " {0}")

                'Set the Default Time.
                Dim scheduledTime As DateTime = DateTime.MinValue

                If mode.ToUpper() = "DAILY" Then
                    'Get the Scheduled Time from AppSettings.
                    scheduledTime = DateTime.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ScheduledTime"))
                    If DateTime.Now > scheduledTime Then
                        'If Scheduled Time is passed set Schedule for the next day.
                        scheduledTime = scheduledTime.AddDays(1)
                    End If
                End If

                If mode.ToUpper() = "INTERVAL" Then
                    'Get the Interval in Minutes from AppSettings.
                    Dim intervalMinutes As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("IntervalMinutes"))

                    'Set the Scheduled Time by adding the Interval to Current Time.
                    scheduledTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(intervalMinutes)
                    If DateTime.Now > scheduledTime Then
                        'If Scheduled Time is passed set Schedule for the next Interval.
                        scheduledTime = scheduledTime.AddMinutes(intervalMinutes)
                    End If
                End If

                Dim timeSpan As TimeSpan = scheduledTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now)
                Dim schedule As String = String.Format("{0} day(s) {1} hour(s) {2} minute(s) {3} seconds(s)", timeSpan.Days, timeSpan.Hours, timeSpan.Minutes, timeSpan.Seconds)

                Me.WriteToFile((Convert.ToString("Iran Stock Codal Service scheduled to run after: ") & schedule) + " {0}")

                'Get the difference in Minutes between the Scheduled and Current Time.
                Dim dueTime As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(timeSpan.TotalMilliseconds)

                'Change the Timer's Due Time.
                Schedular.Change(dueTime, Timeout.Infinite)
            Catch ex As Exception
                WriteToFile("Iran Stock Codal Service Error on: {0} " + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace)

                'Stop the Windows Service.
                Using serviceController As New System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController("IranStockCodal")
                    serviceController.[Stop]()
                End Using
            End Try
        End Sub

        Private Sub SchedularCallback(e As Object)
            Me.WriteToFile("Iran Stock Codal Service Log: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"))
            Me.ScheduleService()
        End Sub

        Private Sub WriteToFile(text As String)
            Dim path As String = "C:\ServiceLog.txt"
            Using writer As New StreamWriter(path, True)
                writer.WriteLine(String.Format(text, DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")))
                writer.Close()
            End Using
        End Sub
    End Class
```

Here is Project Installed Codes:

```
    Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Configuration.Install

Public Class ProjectInstaller

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()

        'This call is required by the Component Designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        'Add initialization code after the call to InitializeComponent

    End Sub
    Protected Overrides Sub OnAfterInstall(savedState As IDictionary)
        MyBase.OnAfterInstall(savedState)

        'The following code starts the services after it is installed.
        Using serviceController As New System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController(ServiceInstaller1.ServiceName)
            serviceController.Start()
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Sub ServiceInstaller1_AfterInstall(sender As Object, e As InstallEventArgs) Handles ServiceInstaller1.AfterInstall

    End Sub

    Private Sub ServiceProcessInstaller1_AfterInstall(sender As Object, e As InstallEventArgs) Handles ServiceProcessInstaller1.AfterInstall

    End Sub
End Class
```

Here is ComponentModel codes

```
    <System.ComponentModel.RunInstaller(True)> Partial Class ProjectInstaller
    Inherits System.Configuration.Install.Installer

    'Installer overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Required by the Component Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Component Designer
    'It can be modified using the Component Designer.  
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()>
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.ServiceProcessInstaller1 = New System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller()
        Me.ServiceInstaller1 = New System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller()
        '
        'ServiceProcessInstaller1
        '
        Me.ServiceProcessInstaller1.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.LocalSystem

        '
        'ServiceInstaller1
        '
        Me.ServiceInstaller1.ServiceName = "IranStockCodal"
        Me.ServiceInstaller1.StartType = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceStartMode.Automatic
        '
        'ProjectInstaller
        '
        Me.Installers.AddRange(New System.Configuration.Install.Installer() {Me.ServiceProcessInstaller1, Me.ServiceInstaller1})

    End Sub
    Friend WithEvents ServiceProcessInstaller1 As System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller
    Friend WithEvents ServiceInstaller1 As System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller

End Class
```

Comment: Normally when I see that kind of behavior is because the service is crashing on startup, since you can run it as a console app, likely culprit is probably permissions.  Is the "C:\ServiceLog.txt" file being created and the startup even being logged?

Comment: @Hursey  When I uninstall and install the service or start it manually the new startup log time is recorded. but it does not continue to run "VbsRun4".

Comment: So it’s not writing any error to your log file?

Comment: @Hursey No, It is not. The output is just this: "Iran Stock Codal started at 25/08/2020 01:10:48 PM"

Comment: Few things to try.  Can you attach the debugger to the service, might throw some light on the problem. Next thing, try changing the user the service runs as to something with more rights

Comment: @Hursey I followed Microsoft's  "How to: Debug Windows Service Applications" topic but my service could not be found in all users process list when trying to attache it. Besides I changed the credential from "Local System" to my local account and install it again and get this error in "Services window": Error 1064, an exception occurred in the service when handling the control request"

Comment: Well, next thing I would look at, are you able to see there service in the services app?  Maybe the issue isn't the service it self but the installation.